# Can I delete user messages with a Telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

In a private chat (a user and a Bot) is it possible to delete user messages (or text commands after pressing a custom keyboard button)to keep the chat clean and more readable?

I'm looking for a solution that acts like inline keyboard mechanism (a label for the button and a command to send).

I have tested the `deletemessageasync` and I was able to remove the Bot sent messages, but couldn't remove user messages.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In private chats a bot can delete only his own messages.
in a group or supergroup he can delete only his own messages as normal users; he can delete messages from anyone if he is an administrator.

If your goal is to keep chat clean, there are no other solutions than using inline keyboards and editing messages.

Answer (score 3):

**Not possible** to delete others message in Telegram, bots don't have more permission than normal users.

BTW, if you are in Supergroup, you can use [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method when you have external permission.

Answer (score 2):

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:AAAAAAAAAA-5555-YOUBOT/deleteMessage?chat_id=-5555&message_id=800`
```

Your bot must be group administrator

To get the messages you can use:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:AAAAAAAAAA-5555-YOUBOT/getUpdates
```

Answer (score 2):

**It's possible**

you can delete messages sent by a user to the bot in private chats since bot API 4.2 released

here is the release note: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#april-14-2019

> The method [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) can now be used to delete messages sent by a user to the bot in private chats within 48 hours.